# How to select Radio button in Uiautomator

Tags: android-uiautomator

How to select Radio button in Uiautomator?

Eg: i've a radio button to switch on my wireless in my LG phone.How to select these radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use

```
UiObject dataValue = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(RadioButton.class.getName()).index(0));
        dataValue.click();
```